# Get positions of max value(s) in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 4, 7],
    'col2': [5, 2, 9],
    'col3': [3, 8, 6],
})
```

How might I get the positions of the max n values?

e.g.

```
max_val_positions(df, n=2)
```

Might give output:

```
[(col2, 2), (col3, 1)]  # [(column name, row index), ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `unstack` + `nlargest`

```
df.unstack().nlargest(2)

col2  2    9
col3  1    8
dtype: int64



#l = df.unstack().nlargest(2).index.tolist()
#[('col2', 2), ('col3', 1)]
```